# SQL: Aggregate different months from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

Lets say I have a table with sales at dates for products. Alas, I cant format a table in here, therefore as code:

```
table1:

Product|Date|Sales
-------|----|-----
ProdA  |1.1.|100
ProdB  |1.1.| 50
ProdC  |1.1.| 75
ProdA  |2.1.|110
ProdB  |2.1.| 60
ProdC  |2.1.| 60
....   |... |...
```

I need a new table with the sales sum for each month:

```
Product| Jan| Feb|...
-------|----|----|...
ProdA  |1234|1400|...
ProdB  | 234| 400|...
ProdC  | 524| 640|...
...    |... |... |...
```

I try to use an SQL-query with `CASE`. Text in [] is a abbreviation, the real expression is a `to_char(to_month(..)) construct` that works.

```sql
SELECT 
    Product,
    CASE WHEN [date == 1] THEN SUM(Sales) END AS Jan,
    CASE WHEN [date == 2] THEN SUM(Sales) END AS Feb,
    CASE WHEN [date == 3] THEN SUM(Sales) END AS Mar,
    ...
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    Product
```

I got an `00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"` error.

I know I could work around by building tables for every month and add some again together, but that is low-performance. I also want to understand, why the construct does not work ?

PS:
- [Edit1]: Its an Oracle DB

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: `to_char(to_month(..))` - I'm not sure I understand this. Oracle doesn't have a `to_month()` function. In any case it is best to treat dates as dates.

Comment: I just shortcutted that, because it is not relevant, but the cut out expression is: `to_Number(to_char(date,'MM'))=2`. The date field is indeed a date. I guess, there are better ways, but that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to give `agreegation` before `case` statement `sum(case when end)`

```
SELECT 
    Product,
    sum(CASE WHEN date = 1 THEN Sales END) AS Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = 2 THEN Sales END) AS Feb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = 3 THEN Sales END) AS Mar,
    ...
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    Product
```

Comment: At least, that does not throw the error. First tests showed correct data. What is the difference? Why does this work?

Comment: you were agreegating data inside case statement so it will not treat it as whole agreegated data. thats why it is showing not a group by expression